# Is Hebe related to the concept of Xenia?

Tags: comparative

Does anyone knows if theres classical reference for relating the Goddess Hebe with Xenia or Theoxenia (receiving well the guests)?

I found relations of Hebe with marriage and pardoning supplicants, but no relation to Xenia, which I thought would be obvious: 
Her images are often of an Eagle that just landed drinking on an Amphor, this could represent an hospitality relation.

If Hebe is not related to Xenia, there would be an explanation for this?

Thanks